# Prove columns in a matrix are orthogonal to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

> Show that if $M$ is a symmetric matrix and $Q^{−1} M Q$ is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries different, then the columns of $Q$ are orthogonal to each other.

---

I know that M being symmetric means that $M = M^T$, and for the columns to be orthogonal to each other, $\langle u, v \rangle = 0$ for all of the vectors, but I'm having trouble connecting the dots in between. I was also very unsure how $Q^{−1}MQ$ being diagonal has to do with the vectors being orthogonal.

Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: hint: try computing $\mathbf q_1^T M \mathbf q_2$ two different ways